# Using Goggles or Zxing Barcode scanner with a PhoneGap application

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build, zxing

I am trying to set up my current app (it's a HTML5 application compiled with phonegap build) where when I press a button, it pops up an option to select which bar code scanner to use(Or prompt to download the bar code scanner). When I select and scan it, I want to retrieve the information.

For example:

Retrieving via Zxing scanner would give me a set of numbers.

Retrieving via Goggles will give me more information like the number and product details.

I have seen some guides which are for native Android where they use Zxing but not Goggles. Seen no guides for using Goggles in an application. Closest I saw is a reverse engineered attempt dated few years back and not for HTML5 plat.

All I need to do is press a button from my app, go out into one of the scanner apps and retrieve the information back to my app to display.

Is there anyway I can do this? Is there a set of APIs available to access Zxing and Goggles via a HTML5/PhoneGap application?

It is definitely possible. Seen it on few applications.

This one for example: [An app on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.petersson.inventory&hl=en_GB)

Please assist.

Screenshot additions for reference.

**Screenshot 1**

[image: Screenshot 1]

**Screenshot 2**

[image: Screenshit 2]

Comment: -1 and a close? Care to explain why? No similar questions asked and no solutions provided. Pretty easy to down vote without giving any reasons.

Comment: there are a few barcode scanner plugins you can use, just search for them

Comment: @jcesarmobile Did find a plugin but using it to scan outputs just numbers. Now this is pretty much the same as Zxing but as mentioned above am also looking to use Goggles. When you use Goggles to scan, you get more information, most importantly the product description in a string.

Comment: yeah, most of the existing plugins use zxing, some others use skandit, but there is no plugin for goggles as google doesn't provide an API to access it or an intent to return you the values you want.

Comment: I added 2 screenshots for reference. First one is a prompt after I click Scan Barcode which allows me to use Goggles. Second one shows description details of the product after scanning it. Without Goggles API access, how is this possible. Seen this in a few applications.

Comment: I've tested that app and it gets the product data even if you use zxing. They get the data from an online service.

Comment: Maybe its just my luck but with the zxing option, my odds of getting a description is 1/10 items I scan compared to Goggles which is pretty much a 10/10. What do you mean by online service. Can you give an example. Reply as an answer if you can.

Comment: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/562/does-there-exist-a-global-database-of-all-products-with-ean-13-barcodes http://barcode.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page